# Not able to increase innodb_buffer_pool_size value

Tags: mysql, database, performance, innodb, ini

MY Query:  SHOW STATUS like '%innodb%';

MY data: Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data,411
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty,0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed,0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free,65125
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc,0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total,65536
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead,0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted,0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests,2709
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads,412
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free,0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests,0
Innodb_data_fsyncs,3
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs,0
Innodb_data_pending_reads,0
Innodb_data_pending_writes,0
Innodb_data_read,8933376
Innodb_data_reads,422
Innodb_data_writes,3
Innodb_data_written,1536...
My server : OS Windows 7, 16 GB Ram, Intel R xeon R processor

My problem is when i try to increase the innodb_buffer_pool_size value i got mysql error 1067.. 
 I can able to increase this value upto 1G , currently now 512M. if im trying to increase this value more than 1G im facing 1067 mysql error and it stopped my mysql service.. I think that we can increase this value upto 80% of ram memory. Can some help me why im getting this issue? because i need to do this for improving my db performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [known bug](http://forums.innodb.com/read.php?3,315,325#msg-325) that may be affecting you.

Avoid values that are congruent with 0 modulo 2^32.  This is an example setting that works, even if you are affected:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8191M
```

and this one does not:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8192M
```

Comment: Thanks for reply... my machine is 64 bit and also i tried as per your advice but i'm getting the same result.. My database size is 6 GB and my queries are very slow even though i indexed and optimized my queries as well.. so that only i would like to change this value

Comment: Thank you very much for that link... You are right this bug is already in mysql. Now i can able to increase it up to 4095M. Great work and thanks again